# when i replay the game its speed increase from previous speed and game crashed in corona sdk for android platform

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I went through some of help and with that I removed all variables, timer, event listener at exit of screen. but still I'm facing the same issue i.e. the first time when I play the game, its working fine and when I replay the game then its speed increases by itself and app crashes lastly.

There are some obstacles that I added in game, due to which its happening. So when I make them as comment, its work fine.
I'm adding those variables here:-

------------------------CREATE BIRDS----------------------------

```
            currentXLocObstacleBird = currentXLocObstacleBird - SCREEN_WIDTH      
    while (currentXLocObstacleBird < SCREEN_WIDTH) do
        obstacleType = math.random(4)
        local  birdHeight = math.random(display.topStatusBarContentHeight + 200, display.contentHeight - 200)
        if (obstacleType % 2 == 0) then  -- one in two chance of displaying a each of the snake
            obstacleType = mathDiv(obstacleType, 2)                
            if (obstacleType == 1) then
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdY = display.newSprite( otherSpriteSheet , birdSequenceData2)
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdY:play()
                if (a == 1) then  -- if it is for first screen then start from zero otherwise start from loc+screnwidth ie. second screen
                    obstacles_Variables.imgBirdY.x = currentXLocObstacleBird
                    birdYPolygon = display.newPolygon(currentXLocObstacleBird, birdHeight, {0,20, 50,0, 115,50, 50,40 })
                else
                    obstacles_Variables.imgBirdY.x = currentXLocObstacleBird + SCREEN_WIDTH
                    birdYPolygon = display.newPolygon(currentXLocObstacleBird + SCREEN_WIDTH, birdHeight, {0,20, 50,0, 115,50, 50,40 }) -- birdShape)
                    physics.addBody(birdYPolygon, "static",{density = 0, bounce = 0, friction = 0 })                        
                end 
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdY.y = birdHeight
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdY.name = "yelloBird1" 
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdY.screenIndex = a     -- indicates which screen this object belongs to (from SCREENS_PER_LEVEL)
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdY.isVisible = false
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdY.speed = Speed_Constant_Array.SPEED_BIRD_1
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdY:rotate(15)                    
                groupObstacles:insert(obstacles_Variables.imgBirdY)                    
--                    birdYPolygon.name = "yelloBird"
--                    birdYPolygon.screenIndex = a
--                    birdYPolygon.isVisible = false
--                    birdYPolygon.speed = Speed_Constant_Array.SPEED_BIRD_1
--                    groupObstacles:insert(birdYPolygon)
                currentXLocObstacleBird = currentXLocObstacleBird + 2 * WIDTH_YELLOW_BIRD    

            elseif(obstacleType == 2) then
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdG = display.newSprite( otherSpriteSheet , birdSequenceData)
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdG:play()
                if (a == 1) then  -- if it is for first screen then start from zero otherwise start from loc+screnwidth ie. second screen
                    obstacles_Variables.imgBirdG.x = currentXLocObstacleBird
                   birdGPolygon = display.newPolygon(currentXLocObstacleBird, birdHeight, {0,20, 50,0, 115,50, 50,40 }) --birdShape2)
                else
                    obstacles_Variables.imgBirdG.x = currentXLocObstacleBird + SCREEN_WIDTH 
                    birdGPolygon = display.newPolygon(currentXLocObstacleBird + SCREEN_WIDTH, birdHeight, {0,20, 50,0, 115,50, 50,40 }) --birdShape2)
                    physics.addBody(birdGPolygon, "static",{density = 0, bounce = 0, friction = 0 })                    
                end
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdG.y = birdHeight
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdG.name = "greenBird1"
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdG.screenIndex = a     -- indicates which screen this object belongs to (from SCREENS_PER_LEVEL)
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdG:rotate(15)
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdG.speed = Speed_Constant_Array.SPEED_BIRD_2
                obstacles_Variables.imgBirdG.isVisible = false
                groupObstacles:insert(obstacles_Variables.imgBirdG)

--                    birdGPolygon.name = "greenBird"
--                    birdGPolygon.screenIndex = a     -- indicates which screen this object belongs to (from SCREENS_PER_LEVEL)
--                    birdGPolygon.isVisible = false
--                    birdGPolygon.speed = Speed_Constant_Array.SPEED_BIRD_2
--                    birdGPolygon:setFillColor(1,0,0,0)
--                    groupObstacles:insert(birdGPolygon)

                currentXLocObstacleBird = currentXLocObstacleBird + 2 *            WIDTH_GREEN_BIRD
            end                
        end
        currentXLocObstacleBird = currentXLocObstacleBird + math.random(500, 700)  -- add some spacing for the next decor
        end
```

---

Comment: Consider adding the platform you're working on (android?) to the tag list. The corona tag by itself probably wont generate many views.

Comment: yes i am working for Android platform

Comment: in my code when use comment then its work fine. if i remove comment then its speed increase in next reply

Comment: finally i resolved that issue. the issue was not in this code as i shown above, this was resolved only temporarly. but again same issue started. the solution of this issue was trying to remove and cancel all addEventListener and timer.performWithdelay, this is only the solution of these type of issue. in starting we may not identify but when we try our code to run without this functionality then we can easily identify that this was only issue and by removing all event listener and cancel timer one by one will resolve our issue also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i resolved that issue. the issue was not in this code as i shown above, this was resolved only temporarly. but again same issue started. the solution of this issue was trying to remove and cancel all addEventListener and timer.performWithdelay, this is only the solution of these type of issue. in starting we may not identify but when we try our code to run without this functionality then we can easily identify that this was only issue and by removing all event listener and cancel timer one by one will resolve our issue also